# How can I pass parameters in a Stored Procedure in MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure to fetch the Class of a Student like this:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LocateT2(IN name varchar(100)) BEGIN SELECT Class FROM Students WHERE Name = name; END$
```

Here is the description of the Table Students:-

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SerialID | varchar(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Name     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Email    | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| Phone    | char(10)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SEX      | varchar(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DOB      | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Course   | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Class    | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Whenever I am calling this procedure (call LocateT2("Alex")) it's somehow selecting all the Class names present in the table, not just of the one that's passed as parameter.

Here is the list of Names and Classes:-

```
+----------------+-------+
| Name           | Class |
+----------------+-------+
| Akimichi Choji | XI-C  |
| Neji Hyuga     | X-A   |
| Ino Yamanaka   | XI-C  |
| Rock Lee       | X-A   |
| Shikamaru Nara | XI-C  |
| Ten Ten        | X-A   |
| Sakura Haruno  | X-B   |
| Sasuke Uchiha  | X-B   |
| Naruto Uzumaki | X-B   |
+----------------+-------+
```

if I call LocateT2("Sasuke Uchiha"); 
 Instead of returning

```
+-------+
| Class |
+-------+
| X-B   |
+-------+
```

It's returning :-

```
+-------+
| Class |
+-------+
| XI-C  |
| X-A   |
| XI-C  |
| X-A   |
| XI-C  |
| X-A   |
| X-B   |
| X-B   |
| X-B   |
+-------+
```

Please help me with this

Comment: rename your paramater `name` to some other name, which is different than the name of an existing column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql doesn't know , what ios what when you name variables like their column names

so rename your variable

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Students
>     (`Name` varchar(14), `Class` varchar(4))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Students
>     (`Name`, `Class`)
> VALUES
>     ('Akimichi Choji', 'XI-C'),
>     ('Neji Hyuga', 'X-A'),
>     ('Ino Yamanaka', 'XI-C'),
>     ('Rock Lee', 'X-A'),
>     ('Shikamaru Nara', 'XI-C'),
>     ('Ten Ten', 'X-A'),
>     ('Sakura Haruno', 'X-B'),
>     ('Sasuke Uchiha', 'X-B'),
>     ('Naruto Uzumaki', 'X-B')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE LocateT2(IN _name varchar(100)) 
> BEGIN 
> SELECT Class FROM Students WHERE Name = _name; 
> end
> ```

> ```
> call LocateT2("Sasuke Uchiha");
> ```
>
> ```
> | Class |
> | :---- |
> | X-B   |
>
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6dd7bf3438639919f7bac39efad26bea)*